# Is there any way to Authenticate B2C application using multiple policies

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-ad-b2c

I am using a B2C login page to authenticate my users. These users have multiple IDP's of their choice as per their business and I created multiple policies with selected IDP's. In the login page based on the user email, I display his login page which has only his relevant IDP's. But in my web application, I can only add **one** **Signup or SignIn policy** in my appsettings.json to authenticate the user. Is there any option to have multiple policies in appsettings.json file or any other way to handle this requirement

My Current appsettings.json looks like below

```
"AzureAdB2C": {
"Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/tfp/",
"ClientId": "******-***-****-****-*******",
"Domain": "mycustomdomain.onmicrosoft.com",
"SignUpSignInPolicyId": "Org-signinsignout"
```

},

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Azure B2C - Single App with multiple login for different user types setup in Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51737621/azure-b2c-single-app-with-multiple-login-for-different-user-types-setup-in-azu)

Comment: @MohitVerma-MSFT my requirement is different, the above one for different users login page and policy is same but my case requires different login page(different policy) with different IDP's.

Comment: Did you check my answer below, i have posted the answer for different policy too. Isn't  it something you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

You can invoke a different policy for a different type of user by [passing the requested policy from a controller method to the authentication middleware](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-external-identities-woodgrove-demo/blob/2b5110c25d1a626bf9b9ac27ecaaabad8b4bccf4/src/WoodGroveGroceriesWebApplication/Controllers/AccountController.cs#L58):

```
  public IActionResult LogInForBusinessCustomer(string uiLocale)
        {
            return LogInFor(Constants.AuthenticationSchemes.B2COpenIdConnect, Constants.Policies.SignUpOrSignInWithWorkAccount, uiLocale);
        }

    public IActionResult LogInForIndividualCustomer(string uiLocale)
    {
        return LogInFor(Constants.AuthenticationSchemes.B2COpenIdConnect, Constants.Policies.SignUpOrSignInWithPersonalAccount, uiLocale);
    }

    public IActionResult LogInForPartner(string uiLocale)
    {
        return LogInFor(Constants.AuthenticationSchemes.B2BOpenIdConnect, null, uiLocale);
    }

private IActionResult LogInFor(string authenticationScheme, string policy)
{
    if (!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        return new ChallengeResult(
            authenticationScheme,
            new AuthenticationProperties(
                new Dictionary<string, string>
                {
                    {Constants.AuthenticationProperties.Policy, policy}
                })
            {
                RedirectUri = Url.Action("LoggedIn", "Account", values: null, protocol: Request.Scheme)
            });
    }

    return RedirectToHome();
}
```

and then setting the redirection URL for the requested policy in the authentication middleware:

```
OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = async context =>
            {
                var policy = context.Properties.Items.ContainsKey(Constants.AuthenticationProperties.Policy) ? context.Properties.Items[Constants.AuthenticationProperties.Policy] : Constants.Policies.SignUpOrSignInWithPersonalAccount;
                var configuration = await GetB2COpenIdConnectConfigurationAsync(context, policy);
                context.ProtocolMessage.IssuerAddress = configuration.AuthorizationEndpoint;

                if (context.Properties.Items.ContainsKey(Constants.AuthenticationProperties.UILocales))
                {
                    context.ProtocolMessage.SetParameter("ui_locales", context.Properties.Items[Constants.AuthenticationProperties.UILocales]);
                }

                context.ProtocolMessage.SetParameter("dc", "cdm");
                context.ProtocolMessage.SetParameter("slice", "001-000");
            },
```

Reference: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-external-identities-woodgrove-demo/blob/2b5110c25d1a626bf9b9ac27ecaaabad8b4bccf4/src/WoodGroveGroceriesWebApplication/Startup.cs#L283

Also please check out this thread

[Azure B2C - Single App with multiple login for different user types setup in Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51737621/azure-b2c-single-app-with-multiple-login-for-different-user-types-setup-in-azu/51741384)

Hope it helps.

Comment: When the request came to a server, first I need to authenticate the B2C user, to authenticate I need to know the SignuP or SignIn policy name. After that only I can read the claims I can't know what is the policy.

Comment: Have you checked this site https://woodgrovegroceriesb2c.azurewebsites.net/ in the example i posted above , Basically you need to keep different login option and while user clicked on the options, you need to call the respected policy for the same.